# Is it possible to deploy lightning web components to an org with an api version lower than 45?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'd like to start developing LWCs in my dev sandbox, but it's current api version is 44. I get this error when trying to deploy my lwc.

> Starting SFDX: Deploy Source to Org
>
> 19:30:37.961 sfdx force:source:deploy --json --loglevel fatal --sourcepath /Users/tyler/code/salesforce/HelloWorld/force-app/main/default/lwc
> {"message":"Deploy failed.","status":1,"stack":"DeployFailed: Deploy failed.\n    at ALMError (/Users/tyler/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/almError.js:44:19)\n    at MetadataRegistry.initializeMetadataTypeInfos.then.catch.e (/Users/tyler/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/source/sourceApiCommand.js:67:35)\n    at tryCatcher (/Users/tyler/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)\n    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/tyler/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)\n    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/tyler/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:567:18)\n    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/tyler/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:612:10)\n    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/tyler/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:687:18)\n    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/tyler/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:16)\n    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/tyler/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)\n    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/tyler/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)\n    at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)\n    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)\n    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)","name":"DeployFailed","result":[{"error":"Invalid version specified:45.0","type":"","filePath":"N/A"}],"warnings":["All --json output, including on error, is moving to stdout. Use the SFDX_JSON_TO_STDOUT environment variable to move over to the new functionality. This will become the default in version 45."]}
> 19:30:40.979 sfdx force:source:deploy --json --loglevel fatal --sourcepath /Users/tyler/code/salesforce/HelloWorld/force-app/main/default/lwc ended with exit code 1

Has anyone else been able to successfully deploy a lwc to an org with an api version that is not 45?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer , you will need pre-release org and API version 45 atleast.

1. Sign up here for the pre-release org https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring19/
2. You will need pre-release CLI plugin to scaffold the bundle .Install the SFDX CLI (https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli) and then install pre release DX plugin `sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release`.
3. Install the VScode extension pack for salesforce https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode to get syntax autocomplete , deploy and other language features .

Comment: I'd like to start developing in my dev sandbox now. Do I need to wait till salesforce updates it? How can I get a pre-release org in the mean time?

Comment: Sign up here https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring19/

Comment: @TylerZika If you have Sandboxes that will be upgraded, you can do this against your (sandbox copy of) production code too, starting January 4th.

Comment: I have pre-release dev org, I have 45.0.12 (pre-release) CLI but I'm still getting this issue following [Trailhead instructions](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component)

Comment: I even literally just recreated my org using the link you provided and it still comes back with "sourceApiVersion": "44.0"